# Get Azure/Msol users created in last 24hrs. Or Today

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get users created in last 24 hours or today, from Azure or Msol. But whatever I tried is not working;

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))
Get-AzureADUser -Filter {(whenCreated -ge $When)} -Properties whenCreated
```

But it gives me this error;

```
Get-AzureADUser : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Filter' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is 
no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:6 char:25
+ Get-AzureADUser -Filter {(whenCreated -ge $When)} -Properties whenCre ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser
```

Comment: The error message shows exactly what the error is, if you look at the MS docs page for this cmdlet you will see that you are using the filter command incorrectly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0 . The syntax you want to use is like this: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | Where {$_.whenCreated -ge $datecutoff}`

Comment: Okay.. Thanks. I made some changes and tried this; $Today = Get-Date -Format D
Get-AzureADuser | Where-Object {(($_.WhenCreated) -eq $Today)} | fl name, whencreated
But this doesn't return any data at all.